# ERROR PHP "Blank line found at end of control structure"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, control-structure

I made a simple, posting system. But on the `if isset`  i made it, keeps saying  `Blank line found at end of control structure` But i really cant find the solution and already tried many options, like moving the closing brace etc.  **The error is on line 26 in this part of the code:**

```
        if (isset($_POST['like'])) {
            $id = $_POST['like'];
            $query2 = "UPDATE `posts` SET `likes` = likes + 1 WHERE id = '$id'";
            $run = $conn->query($query2);
        }
```

*If Someone knows the fix for this i would highly apreciate it!*

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php

    try {
        include 'connection.php';
        $query = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM auteurs INNER JOIN posts ON auteurs.id = posts.auteur_id ORDER BY posts.likes DESC');    
            
        # Haal hier alle posts uit de data base op.
        ?>

    <div class="container">
    <div id='header'>
            <h1>Foodblog</h1>
            <a href='new_post.php'><button>Nieuwe post</button></a>
</span>

    </div>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['like'])) {
            $id = $_POST['like'];
            $query2 = "UPDATE `posts` SET `likes` = likes + 1 WHERE id = '$id'";
            $run = $conn->query($query2);
        }
        
        foreach ($query as $info) {
            ?> 
            <div class='post'>
                <div class='header'>
                <h2><?php echo  $info['titel']; ?></h2>
                <img src="<?php echo $info['img_url']; ?>" />
            </div>
                <span class=right>
                <form action='index.php' method='post'>
                <button type='submit'value=<?php echo $info['id']; ?> name='like'>
                <?php echo $info['likes']; ?> likes
                </button>
            </form>
            </span>
                <span class='details'>Geschreven op: <?php echo $info['datum']; ?>  door: <?php echo $info['auteur']; ?>
                </span>
                <p><?php echo $info['inhoud']; ?> </p>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    } catch (Exception $query) {
        echo $query->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a PSR2 structure warning and is most likely coming from your IDE or code sniffer and not the PHP code. While I don't see a blank line, you can ignore it

Comment: Yea Thats what i thought aswell, but its a school excersice and we need to get it to a some sort of a debugger... and it keeps fishing this ```Blank line found at end of control structure``` error (otherwise we cant hand it in...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's the line 26 and not 10 ?
There is one blank line

```php
<?php

    try {
        include 'connection.php';
        $query = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM auteurs INNER JOIN posts ON auteurs.id = posts.auteur_id ORDER BY posts.likes DESC');    
            
        # Haal hier alle posts uit de data base op.
        ?>
```

And your code is subject to sql injections

```php
$query2 = "UPDATE `posts` SET `likes` = likes + 1 WHERE id = '$id'";
            $run = $conn->query($query2);
```

Here you can find more info to prevent hack
https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Yeaa, i was aware of SQL Injections. But its a school project we dont need to worry about that right now... (But yeah im sure its on line 26, i removed the blank line on line 10,  and it made no difference.

Comment: What tools and config are used and what is the error ouput ? When i create a php file with your snippet and the commande `phpcs --standard=psr2 test.php` the is no error on line 26